# Find Range Values where X is the Mid Point

Tags: r

I've got a set of numbers from 0 to 1.  Given a value X in the set, I'd like to find the range values (high and low) where Y% of the values in the set are within high and low and where X is the mid point.

So let's say the numbers are evenly distributed.  Given X=0.4 and Y=20%, I need a function that will give me:

high = 0.5
low  = 0.3

How can I do that in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** In light of the extra info from the comments, this will do what the OP wants:

```
foobar <- function(x, mid, y) {
    ## x, input data on range 0,1
    ## mid, midpoint X in OP's Q
    ## y, % of points around mid
    sx <- sort(x)
    want <- sx >= mid
    ## what do you want to do if y% of x is not integer?
    num <- floor(((y/100) * length(x)) / 2)
    high <- if((len <- length(want[want])) == 0) {
        1
    } else {
        if(len < num) {
            tail(sx, 1)
        } else {
            sx[want][num]
        }
    }
    low <- if((len <- length(want[!want])) == 0) {
        0
    } else {
        if(len < num) {
            head(sx, 1)
        } else {
            rev(sx[!want])[num]
        }
    }
    res <- c(low, high)
    names(res) <- c("low","high")
    res
}
```

Which gives the following on a sample of random values on interval 0,1:

```
> set.seed(1)
> x <- runif(20)
> sort(x)
 [1] 0.06178627 0.17655675 0.20168193 0.20597457 0.26550866 0.37212390
 [7] 0.38003518 0.38410372 0.49769924 0.57285336 0.62911404 0.66079779
[13] 0.68702285 0.71761851 0.76984142 0.77744522 0.89838968 0.90820779
[19] 0.94467527 0.99190609
> foobar(x, 0.4, 20)
      low      high 
0.3800352 0.5728534
```

*The OP has answered the Qs below and the version of the function above does as was requested and in light of comments.*

There are a couple of issues to deal with:

- **What do you want to do if `y`% of the data is not an integer?** At the moment, if `y`% of the data evaluates to say `4.2` I am rounding down to `floor(4.2)` but we could round up to `ceiling(4.2)`.
- **What do you want to do if there are 0 values above or below the chosen mid point?** At the moment the code returns the stated extremes (0,1) in those cases.
- **What do you want to do if there are some values above/below the mid point but not enough in a given direction to encompass `y/2`% in any one direction?** At the moment I return the extreme points of the data that lie above/below the mid point. This is a little inconsistent with the previous point though, should we return the extremes 0, 1 in this case too?

---

**Original:** This will give you what you want, assuming the assumptions you state (evenly distributed on range 0,1)

```
foo <- function(x, y) {
    ## x is the mid-point
    ## y is the % range about x, i.e. y/2 either side of x
    x + (c(-1,1) * (((y/100) / 2) * 1))
}

> foo(0.4, 20)
[1] 0.3 0.5
```

We could extend the function to allow an arbitrary range with defaults 0, 1:

```
bar <- function(x, y, min = 0, max = 1) {
    ## x is the mid-point
    ## y is the % range about x, i.e. y/2 either side of x
    ## min, max, the lower and upper bounds on the data
    stopifnot(x >= min & x <= max)
    x + (c(-1,1) * (((y/100) / 2) * (max - min)))
}

> bar(0.4, 20)
[1] 0.3 0.5
> bar(0.6, 20, 0.5, 1)
[1] 0.55 0.65
> bar(0.4, 20, 0.5, 1)
Error: x >= min & x <= max is not TRUE
```

Comment: I was just using the assumption of even distribution to make the example clearer.  I'll need to use the function on sets that aren't necessarily evenly distributed.

Comment: @Dave Ah, well that is an important disctinction - you mean you want to work out which values are within +/- Y/2% of X and then give the limits? I think that should be easily doable with quantiles. Give me a minute...

Comment: @Dave I think I have it now - see my updated Answer. There are several (3) implementation details that need clarifying as I made a guess at something reasonable but that might not be what you wanted. See the Q's at end of my update.

Comment: @Gavin Wow - great answer!  I think I'd want y/2% at most on either side of mid.  So if mid = max then just then high = max and low = y/2%  below mid.  y will never not be an integer.

Comment: @Dave OK, that sort of answers my Q2. What about my Q3? mid != max but there aren't `y/2`% observations greater than mid? Do you still want it to return max (i.e. 1) in that case? Currently I return the largest value above the mid point. Easy to fix, just need to know what you want? And what about my Q1?

Comment: Yes, return high = max(x).  For Q1, Y will always be an integer so you're solution is perfect.

Comment: @Dave OK, thanks so the function works as you want it. Note that I've fixed a typo in the computing the low part and have got rid of the duplicated calls to length() in the high and low if/else clauses. Glad this was of use.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rather briefer form

```
interval <- function(data, centre, qrange, type=1) {  #type as in ?quantile
    qcentre <- ( length(data[data<centre]) +          #quantile of centre
                 length(data[data == centre])/2 ) / length(data)
    quantile(data, c( max(0, qcentre-qrange/2), qcentre, 
                      min(1, qcentre+qrange/2) ), type=type )  
   }
```

An illustration showing the quantile of the point at or nearest below the specified centre, and the low and high quantiles as well as their values:

```
> set.seed(42)
> interval(data=runif(1000000), centre=0.4, qrange=0.2)
 29.9793%  39.9793%  49.9793% 
0.3003162 0.3999986 0.5001484
```

An illustration that extremes and non-uniform distributions can be handled; note that `sqrt(0.95) = 0.974679...`:

```
> set.seed(123)
> interval(data=runif(100000)^2, centre=0.95, qrange=0.2)
  87.456%   97.456%      100% 
0.7634248 0.9499948 0.9999846
```

And an illustration reproducing Gavin Simpson's example:

```
> set.seed(1)
> interval(data=runif(20), centre=0.4, qrange=0.2)
      30%       40%       50% 
0.3800352 0.3841037 0.5728534
```